# Update multiple MySQL rows based on position in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array (in PHP) that has a list of UIDs and I want to update a MySQL table that already contains rows with those UIDs with the index of where the UID is in the array.

So my array of UIDs may be:

```
[1123,4542,3456,2212,2346,7778,577885,44322]
```

I want to then update the table to the effect of:

```
POS | UID
----------
1   |1123    
2   |4542    
3   |3456    
etc    
----------
```

The dataset (array) could be very large (1000+) and the table that I'm updating also contains other UIDs that are part of other datasets that I don't want to touch (but will have unique UIDs).

I can obviously do this with a loop and a shed load of update statements, but wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it with a single or just a couple of statements.

I've done a lot of searching and can only find answers that relate to a set/fixed number of values or updating based on other database tables, but my array will vary in length depending on the data set being updated.

Comment: Just use **one** prepared update statement and exectue it multiple times in a loop. If that is too slow, you can store your array in a temporary table with a bulk insert.

Comment: Thanks Paul, was hoping to avoid looping if possible due to the potentially high number of updates that I may need to make, but will use that as the fall back position if there isn't a more efficient way of doing it

Comment: You should first test how the simple and trivial solution performs. You might be positively surprised.

Answer (score 0):

If the updates with a prepared statement isn't fast enough for you, you can try to "preload" the data into a temporary table with a bulk insert. Here is a sample code for PDO:

```
// $uids = [1123,4542,3456,2212,2346,7778,577885,44322,...]
$values = [];
foreach ($uids as $key => $uid) {
    $pos = $key+1;
    $values[] = "($uid,$pos)";
}
$values = implode(',', $values);
$pdo->exec("
    drop temporary table if exists tmpdata;
    create temporary table tmpdata (uid int, pos smallint) engine=memory;
    insert into tmpdata(uid, pos) values $values;
    update test d
    join tmpdata t using(uid)
    set d.pos = t.pos;
");
```

I've tested this with an array of 10K UIDs - and it runs in 50ms on my machine.

Note: You might need to validate/sanitize the data to prevent SQL injections.

Also read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-temptables.html) if you use replication.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies all, kept forgetting to update the question - I've gone with the simple option of just looping through the objects and updating each with a new query.

I don't have any specific timings, but there does not appear to be any obvious performance detriment by doing this way so I'm quite happy with the approach

Thanks everyone for the help